# Area with Infinite Enemies?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm pretty new to Diablo 3, just got it last week. I am wondering if there is an area in-game that has unlimited enemies. Such as a spot where the demons keep spawning until you recover an artefact or move past a certain point.

The only spot I found when playing the campaign was right before King Leoric, with his skeleton pillars. Fun, but to easy since it's so early in the game. It'd be nice if there was an area later on that's a little harder and more fun. Not looking to farm experience or anything, just purely for the fun of hack & slash forever.

Comment: ANd the worst part is that IIRC these spawned skeles don't even give xp. Don't think there is any other spot either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are looking for good old hack n slash action, wait until you start running Nephalem Rifts which are designed exaclty for that purpose. Even though the number of enemy is not unlimited the density is really high and once you've complete a Nephalem Rift you can directly jump to another one and start slaying hundreds of mobs again.

If we are talking about infinite spawning mobs late in the game there is one location in act V that is pretty famous. Just follow those steps :

*Note that this method has been nerfed, the monsters still spawn but no longer gives XP or loot.*

1. Go in campaign mode and Select : **Act V** > **Quest 6 The Battlefields of eternity** > **Subquest "Siege Runes"**
2. TP to the **Abandonned Siege Camp** and run to **The Battlefields of Eternity**
3. You need to destroy two runes. The first one is always the same (and doesn't need to be killed). The second one, however, is random. You are looking for an enemy named **Emikdeva** who is part of the event **The Demonic Prisoner**. If the second rune is not guarded by Emikdeva : quit and restart.
4. When you find him, you activate the rune. Then pull Emikdeva as far away from the rune location as you can (**withou killng him**) and die. When you respawn go back to the rune (without aggroing Emikdeva back with you) and start killing the minions that spawns arround the rune.
5. As long as Emikdeva doesn't die, they'll respawn indefinitely.
6. Slay monsters.

Here's a short video I could find on youtube demonstrating this exact method :

Comment: According to the comments (and the fact that's it was public 5 months ago) that method has been nerfed, the mobs don't give XP.

Comment: I tested it myself just now, the mob spawn is infinite, but they don't give any XP or loot.

Comment: @Chippies true, it has infinite monster spawn, but they don't give any loot/exp. Not even gold. Not even with *Boon of the Hoarder* legendary gem. And the amount of monsters spawning there is too little(IMHO), they die even before they spawn :D

Comment: Ow, I didn't know it got nerfed. I'll update my answer